# Magento 2.3 composer install issue

Tags: installation, composer, magento2.3

I am tring to install to get vendor files in magento 2.3 instance using composer.But i am getting following log:

> dealsouq@dcwsrv2401:~/public_html$ composer install
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 191
>   installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Installing vertex/module-tax (3.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>   [UnexpectedValueException]  The checksum verification of the file
>     failed (downloaded from
>     https://repo.magento.com/archives/vertex/module-tax/vertex-module-tax-3.0.0.0.zip)
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...

Any one has idea over this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to remove the vendor folder and try:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```

if it doesn't work try again with:

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

Here's a link if you want to read more about this commands:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079571/installing-laravel-prefer-dist

Answer (score 1):

I have skipped the vertex/module-tax module by adding following code in `composer.json`

```
 "replace": {
            "vertex/module-tax": "*"
    },
```

And now composer install is working fine

Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot! this is working